# Counting the rows in MySQL

Tags: php, sql

I am having trouble with counting the rows in a table. I want to count how many rows there are where `question_id` is the same as `$id.` However, when I echo `$total_records` the result is just 1.

I'm expecting 21. I'm completely sure that the variables and database information is correct. Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
$sqlwow="SELECT COUNT(a_id) 
         FROM forum_answer 
         WHERE question_id='$id' 
         ORDER BY a_id DESC"; 
$rsresult = $mysqli->query($sqlwow);
$row=$rsresult->fetch_assoc();
$total_records = count($row);
echo $total_records;
```

Comment: Try to add `echo $total_pages;` before `for` and see what the value of `$total_pages` is.

Comment: It displays 0. So it's something wrong with getting the $total_pages?

Comment: what if you change `$total_records = @$row[0];` to `$total_records = count($row);`

Comment: There's no difference. I echoed $total_records and it said 1.

Comment: Where's your GET statement?

Comment: I think I found a huge mess-up, I'm going to try fixing it and see if it fixes my problem.

Comment: Never mind. I edited my post and added a bit of stuff I forgot originally. It has my GET statement in it now

Comment: What about `$_GET["id"]`, or is that elsewhere? Since you're using `?id`

Comment: Yeah, I have `$id=$_GET['id'];` up at the beginning of my page. I have a mysql connection and everything too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sqlwow="SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM forum_answer 
         WHERE question_id='$id' 
         ORDER BY a_id DESC"; 
$rsresult = $mysqli->query($sqlwow);
$row = $rsresult->fetch_row();
$total_records = $row[0];
```

You shouldn't fetch as an associative result when all you have is one column.  PDO actually has a shortcut for this using just `fetchColumn` to get the first column.  MySQLi doesn't seem to have this shortcut so you can fetch the whole row as a numeric array then return the first result in that array (the first column) which will be the count.

You should also just use `count(*)` or `count(1)`.  Using a column name is slower as it doesn't check how many rows are returned, but how many non-null values of that column are returned.  In most cases, this is the same, especially if that column is the primary key.  Thanks for the clarification by @fthiella.

Comment: COUNT(*) will count the rows, while COUNT(a_id) will count all rows where a_id is not null, so it actually has an effect on the result, but it depends on the OP's intention

Comment: @fthiella, thanks for the clarification.  From the question's wording, I would assume that this isn't the OP's intention so `count(*)` may even be more accurate unless `a_id` is the primary key and in that case can't be null.

Comment: @fthiella.  I have updated the answer to include more clarification about that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

`count($row)` will always be 1. You need to alias your count in the SQL  statement:

```
$sqlwow="SELECT COUNT(a_id) as num_records 
          FROM forum_answer 
          WHERE question_id='$id'
          ORDER BY a_id DESC";
```

Then echo it as:

`$total_records = $row['num_records'];`

`echo $total_records;`

Comment: You don't have to use an alias.  The alias is only helpful because of the `fetch_assoc()` call.  Since there is only one column, `current($row)` should work fine without an alias or using `fetch_row()` and using `$row[0]` in my query.  This is just a comment based on the "need to alias".